# How to pass angular css class to html page

Tags: css, angular, angular9, angular14

In my component.css file I have a class.

```
.blur-map-report {
  filter: blur(8px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
}
```

In my component.ts file has property something like this

```
hasError = false
```

In my component.html file has another class also called map-report.

```
<div id="map" class="map-report"></div>
```

Here I want to add only blur-map-report class if the hasError becomes true. if not only need to keep `map-error` class. if hasError true I want to keep both the class.

So how can I apply this class conditionally

Comment: `[class.blur-map-report] = "hasError"`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. this is little bit unclear. can you please send me the full answer? like how to apply this 2 inside the dev element

Comment: Just add that to your `div`. The rest can remain as-is. Documentation is [here](https://angular.io/guide/class-binding).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [class binding](https://angular.io/guide/class-binding) to conditionally add the class to your `div`:

```
<div id="map" class="map-report" [class.blur-map-report]="hasError"></div>
```